# how to clear contents of ServletOutputStream?

Tags: java, servlets, io, outputstream

I'm wondering how to delete all contents from ServletOutputStream (or any other OutputStream) in case when exception is occurred at some point and I need outputStream to be empty so that it doesn't include "half of data"

```
doSmthInServlet(HttpServletResponse respone, ....) {
        try {
            ServletOutPutStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            //.....
            //writing to outputstream
            //exception occurred
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // and here I need to clear all the contents of outputStream
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can flush at the end of the try block, If some exceptions occurs then it will be in catch block you can set outputStream = null; and close the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServletResponse.resetBuffer()` to clear the buffer.

`ServletResponse.reset()` to clear the buffer, headers and response code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below reset statement.

ServletOutPutStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

outputStream.resetBuffer();

It is always better to clear the buffer and then start writing into it.